# Strange characters for ohmyz in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I've tried to install Oh My Z into vscode. Seems i am very close but somehow i see strange characters at the end of the line in terminal as shown below. Does anyone knows how could i fix that?
[image]

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "strange characters"?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using MacOSX, use this font: "MesloLGS NF"

Answer (score 2):

As described in "[**Oh My Zsh “agnoster” theme not showing correct font on VSCode ? (ubuntu)**](https://medium.com/@cloverinks/oh-my-zsh-agnoster-theme-not-showing-correct-font-on-vscode-ubuntu-47b5e8dcbada)" from **[Aran Cloverink Chananar](https://gitlab.com/cloverink)**, it is a font issue:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/abertsch/Menlo-for-Powerline.git
cd Menlo-for-Powerline
sudo mv Menlo*.tff /usr/share/fonts
```

The "[Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)" settings "`terminal.integrated.fontFamily`" in VSCode must reference the new Font "`Menlo for Powerline`":

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*8wmaOhHiCowdZbLxBpk46w.png]

Result, as reported by Cloverink:

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/598/1*ju3uP-tAAx0yiOWjrRe_eg.png]

Comment: i suppose some icons of this oh my have to be integrated

Comment: They should be part of the font. On which OS are you?

Comment: I am on Windows 10

Comment: @Arie For Windows, I would recommend a [Powerline font](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/DejaVuSansMono) like [`DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline.ttf`](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/blob/master/DejaVuSansMono/DejaVu%20Sans%20Mono%20for%20Powerline.ttf?raw=true)

Comment: Works for me after restart vscode. I use linux kernel 20.04 debian based.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension of the answer from @jonbondani on how to install `MesloLGS NF` font, just for completeness, if it helps. I've tried it on `macOS 10.15.6 Catalina`.

1. Go to [this](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#manual-font-installation) page for downloading the font manually. Just download the
   four Regular, Bold, Italic, and Bold Italic `MesloLGS NF` font files and double click
   them and select <kbd>Install Font</kbd>.
2. Go to VSCode settings (using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (that is
   a `Comma`) on Mac)and type in `@feature:terminal font`.
3. Enter `MesloLGS NF` as the Font and *restart* VSCode.

Things should work now.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 23.10 with VS Code 1.87.2:

- Install the Powerline fonts from [here](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)
- Clone the repo and then run `./install.sh` from the cloned directory
- Then, set the VSCode **Terminal › Integrated: Font Family** settings to
  **Meslo LG S for Powerline**